# Custom Python module not found when placed in Docker container (with setup.py and entry_points, console_scripts)

Tags: python, docker

I have the following structure of my project:

```
|--Dockerfile
|--requirements.txt
|--setup.py
|--mydummyproject
|--|--__init__.py
|--|--__main__.py
|--|--dummy.py
```

The `dummy.py` has one simple function:

```
import numpy as np
def return_output(*args):
    for a in args:
        print(f"Hello {a}")
    print("Phew!")
    print("We've got numpy:",np.__version__)
```

The `__init__.py` file is there *pro forma* and in `__main__.py` I have a simple `argparse`interface:

```
import argparse
from .dummy import return_output

def command_line_target():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-v','--value', nargs='+',default=["John","Jane"])
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return_output(*args.value)
```

My `setup.py` has the following:

```
from setuptools import setup

with open("requirements.txt", "r") as _f:
    install_reqs = _f.read().strip().split("\n")

setup(name="dummy",
      version="0.0.1",
      package_dir={"mydummyproject": "mydummyproject"},
      install_requires=install_reqs,
      python_requires=">=3.8",
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts': [
              'hello = mydummyproject.__main__:command_line_target'
          ]}
      )
```

So basically once I install it and run something like `hello Mark Johnny` it will run the `return_output` and print out the above.

I've tested this in a test conda environment, and it works. Next step is dockerizing my application. I'm running WSL and Docker Desktop. My `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN python setup.py install
CMD ["hello"]
```

I'm using `docker build -t dummytest` in WSL and it builds it just fine. But when I run it via `docker run dummytest` I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/hello", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('dummy==0.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'hello')())
  File "/usr/local/bin/hello", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mydummyproject'
```

This would imply that my custom module (mydummyproject) was not installed correctly. Is there an error in my Dockerfile?

EDIT1:
I've modified `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install .
CMD ["hello"]
```

I've used command `docker build -t dummy2 .` and command `docker run dummy2`. The error was now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/hello", line 5, in <module>
    from mydummyproject.__main__ import command_line_target
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mydummyproject'
```

I've changed `setup.py` and directory (replaced "mydummyproject" with "dummy") and the error was still:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/hello", line 5, in <module>
    from dummy.__main__ import command_line_target
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dummy'
```

EDIT2:
The solution by Teemu Risku works. The solution is to modify the `setup.py` via `find_packages`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open("requirements.txt", "r") as _f:
    install_reqs = _f.read().strip().split("\n")

setup(name="dummy",
      version="0.0.1",

      packages=find_packages(),
      install_requires=install_reqs,
      python_requires=">=3.8",
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts': [
              'hello = mydummyproject.__main__:command_line_target'
          ]}
      )
```

Comment: Does `RUN pip install .` work better to actually install the package?  (...though I don't know what pip would do differently from plain setuptools here.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Let me try that out and I'll edit the OP with results

Comment: Have you tried to use `cli.py` (it could be anything) instead of `__main__.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

First, in your setup.py remove `package_dir` and replace it with  `packages=find_packages()`. You need to import it, so the setup.py file will look like this:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open("requirements.txt", "r") as _f:
    install_reqs = _f.read().strip().split("\n")

setup(name="dummy",
      version="0.0.1",

      packages=find_packages(),
      install_requires=install_reqs,
      python_requires=">=3.8",
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts': [
              'hello = mydummyproject.__main__:command_line_target'
          ]}
      )
```

`find_packages` will do all the work for you and find and install the mydummyproject, but notice that the hello command needs to use the `mydummyproject`.

Another option would be to use

```
packages=["mydummyproject"],
```

you can leave `package_dir={"mydummyproject": "mydummyproject"},` in place, but it's not really needed, the folder name is implicitly assumed to be the same as in `packages`.

No changes to the Dockerfile are needed.

You can test this by running the image and `docker run -it dummytest bash` and running python from anywhere other than the /app-folder and importing the package in the cli:

`>>> import mydummyproject`

Comment: This works! Thank you.

Comment: Additional question. My command "hello" uses function "command_line_target". Is there a way to use CLI within application with docker. For example, "docker run -t dummy Mark John" will throw out an error.

Comment: For example this works for me: docker run dummy hello -v Mark John